# Ansible URI module with cacert option

Tags: ssl, curl, ansible

I'm trying to do the equivalent of:

`curl -X POST --data <json> --key <path to key> --cert <path to cert> --cacert <path to cacert> --header "Content-Type: application/json" <url>`

in an ansible play. Following the documentation from http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/uri_module.html, there are equivalents for key, cert, X, header, and data, but I haven't found a way to pass in a Certificate Authority file.

I've tried:

```
environment:
  CURL_CA_BUNDLE: <path to cacert>
uri:
  url: <url>
  client_cert: <path to cert>
  client_key: <path to key>
  body: <json>
  method: POST
  body_format: json
```

Since man curl specifies that it will read the environment variable `CURL_CA_BUNDLE`. I have also tried:

```
uri:
  url: <url>
  client_cert: <path to cert>
  client_key: <path to key>
  body: <json>
  method: POST
  body_format: json
  others: --cacert <path to cacert>
```

Neither method has worked. Without the cacert, I am getting the error: "Failed to validate the SSL certificate for `<url>`. Make sure your managed systems have a valid CA certificate installed...". I know that if I pass in `validate_certs=False`, then the method will work, and I know that it works via command line with curl.

Is there another option I can pass into the URI module to bypass this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`uri` module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/net_tools/basics/uri.py) is not cURL, it's full python implementation. So no chance that cURL env-vars or options can work.
The `others` option is documented as "all arguments accepted by the file module also work here", so it simply means that you can use `owner`, `group`, `mode`, etc to set attributes to the `dest`.

`client_cert` and `client_key` were added in the recent 2.4 just to fix [issue #18141](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/18141) and they didn't think about the server TLS auth...

I can see 3 solutions:

- Add your CA certificate into your system certificates (on the target host of the `uri` task) - **only valid with python >= 2.7.9**
- Use the `validate_certs: no` option to disable server certificate validation (so no CA certificate to use)
- Raise an issue (and maybe a PR) to add support of a `cacert` option

Comment: Just to add some notes, I had CA certs installed in /etc/pki/tls/certs and ansible was indeed picking them up. My real issue turned out to be that I was running Python 2.7.5 and support for CAs were added in Python 2.7.9 (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html). I think I having the option to add a cacert file/directory for URI module would be a good addition, so I'll try to submit an issue at some point.

Comment: did you get the solution ?

Comment: @IndraYadav Yes, it did work with `validate_certs: no`

Comment: Just note that you are switching to an insecure mode with `validate_certs: no`.

Comment: Regarding "Add your CA certificate into your system certificates": any idea on how to do this on macOS?

Comment: Why is it that in every SO thread about https issues one of the first suggestions is always to disable security?

Answer (score 4):

Using `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable at task level. Ex task:

```yaml
- name: test uri using a custom cacert file
  environment:
    SSL_CERT_FILE: "{{ cacert_file_path }}"
  uri:
    url: "{{ uri_url }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The pull requests https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/71979 added a `ca_path` parameter to the `uri` module that allows the specification of a file that contains a CA certificate that is used for validation (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#parameter-ca_path).

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, disabling SSL cert validation is not a solution but a workaround.** Second of all, the path to `SSL_CERT_FILE` differs depending on your Linux distribution. This is an example of making Ansible module (Python) to recognize SSL certificate in case of Debian distributio, which worked in my case.

(I am aware that the question is about `uri` module, but the solution should work across Ansible modules)

---

After updating the certificate bundle, for example by `update-ca-certificates`,

```
- name:a task
  get_url:
    url: <url>
    dest: <dest>
  environment:        # Specify SSL cert bundle here. 
    SSL_CERT_FILE: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

---