# Ansible job failed because failed cert validation

Tags: nginx, ansible, ssl-certificate, cert

I run an Ansible job on `server1`. This deploys an application to `server2`.

It fails on this step:

```yaml
- name: Check {{ my_app }} runs at "https://{{ host }}:{{ port }}{{ endpoint }}" - returns a status 200
  uri:
    url: 'https://{{ host }}:{{ port }}{{ endpoint}}'
    return_content: yes
  register: result
  until: result.status == 200
  retries: 5
  delay: 20
```

It gives this error:

> fatal: [server2.url.com]: FAILED! => {
> "attempts": 5,
> "changed": false,
> "invocation": {
> "module_args": {
> "attributes": null,
> "backup": null,
> "body": null,
> "body_format": "raw",
> "client_cert": null,
> "client_key": null,
> "content": null,
> "creates": null,
> "delimiter": null,
> "dest": null,
> "directory_mode": null,
> "follow": false,
> "follow_redirects": "safe",
> "force": false,
> "force_basic_auth": false,
> "group": null,
> "headers": {},
> "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
> "method": "GET",
> "mode": null,
> "owner": null,
> "regexp": null,
> "remote_src": null,
> "removes": null,
> "return_content": true,
> "selevel": null,
> "serole": null,
> "setype": null,
> "seuser": null,
> "src": null,
> "status_code": [
> 200
> ],
> "timeout": 30,
> "unix_socket": null,
> "unsafe_writes": null,
> "url": "https://server2.url.com:1234/my/endpoint",
> "url_password": null,
> "url_username": null,
> "use_proxy": true,
> "validate_certs": true
> }
> },
> "msg": "Failed to validate the SSL certificate for server2.url.com:1234. Make sure your managed systems have a valid CA certificate installed. You can use validate_certs=False if you do not need to confirm the servers identity but this is unsafe and not recommended. Paths checked for this platform: /etc/ssl/certs, /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem, /etc/pki/tls/certs, /usr/share/ca-certificates/cacert.org, /etc/ansible. The exception msg was: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618).",
> "status": -1,
> "url": "https://server2.url.com:1234/my/endpoint"

I think I need to install cert somewhere on `server2` but I'm not sure how or where this is done. I think I have the correct cert though. How do I add it?

Additionally, I'm aware that Ansible uses Python. `server1` has Python 3.6.8 and `server2` has Python 2.7.5. Is there any possible conflict between versions?

Comment: Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47890394/ansible-uri-module-with-cacert-option)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
- name: Check {{ my_app }} runs at "https://{{ host }}:{{ port }}{{ endpoint }}" - returns a status 200
  uri:
    url: 'https://{{ host }}:{{ port }}{{ endpoint}}'
    **validate_certs: no**
    return_content: yes
  register: result
  until: result.status == 200
  retries: 5
  delay: 20
```

Comment: It works if I add that line but I want to validate certs. I think I just need to figure out how to do that correctly.